# MaterializeCss Form input (submit) button

Tags: html, forms, form-submit, materialize

I am asking this question because I was faced we this very problem and found little (unconcise) to none information on the matter, here goes:

**Having an html form, how to properly set up a submit button with materializecss?**

If you try the conventional way, that is:

```
<form>
    <div class="file-field input-field">
        ...
        <input type ="submit" class ="btn waves-effect waves-light" value = "Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is what you'll get:
[image]

As you can see the clickable part is only the middle of the button, and the rest won't trigger the form submition.

---

What i am looking for are  answers (no javascript, just html) that offer alternatives. I'll post my own answer and hope for interesting alternatives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked out great and allows for image inclusion:

```
<div class="row">
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
    Waves.attach('.YOUR-Button-Class', ['waves-button', 'waves-float']);
</script>
```